# Adding output of print function to ggplot chart - r

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=4:13)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

Now I want to add many things to this graph, so I use a big paste function and print the output. Just as an example, say I wanted to add the word 'bananas' inside the x axis label.

```
x <- "bananas"    
print(paste0("+ xlab('Price of", x[1], "')"), quote=F)
```

If I try:

```
p + print(paste0("+ xlab('Price of", x[1], "')"), quote=F)
```

then it obviously does not work. But is there a way of adding the output of this function to the ggplot object 'p' without cutting/pasting from the console?

i.e. so we automatically can execute:

```
p + xlab('Price ofbananas')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `Price of bananas` as the x label, then:

```
p + xlab(paste0("Price of ", x[1]))
```

Remember you're adding the `xlab`, so that should be your outside function. Inside it, you add/create the label you want. No need to print.

**Update**:

I think what you want is `eval(parse(text=xxx))`. For example:

```
add <- paste0("xlab('Price of ", x[1], "')")
p + eval(parse(text=add))
```

Note that I removed the `+` from the text, because you need it next to `p` to connect with `eval`.

I'm not sure why you would do this, but it works.

Comment: I'm looking for a more general solution - I have numerous additional themes/labels/etc to add inside of a function.

Comment: Then just store the output in variables.

Comment: I guess I understood what you want: You want the code `xlab()` and others to be stored inside a variable and them add them all at once, right?